# How do I register new vapidKeys outside FCM console UI

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-messaging, vapid

### Update

As Gerardo pointed out, vapidKey != FCM Token.

I finally got things going, though im unsure if this is the best way to do it.

This was what i needed to generate a *NEW* token:

```
try{
            if(currentToken) await deleteToken(messaging,currentToken)
            if(Notification.permission !== 'granted') await Notification.requestPermission();
            currentToken = await getToken(messaging,vapidKey);
            $.ajax({
                type:"GET",
                url:"/fcm/register-token",
                data:{token:currentToken},
                success:(saved)=>{
                    if(saved) console.log(saved,' New token registered ',currentToken)
                    else console.log('Unable to save token!')
                }
            })
        }
        catch(e){console.log(e)}
```

---

## Question

I am testing FCM for push notifications in javascript. I have a single "Web Push Certificate" (vapidKey) generated manually in the FCM console UI. This works for sending a test notification to a single token, but i am unclear on how any additional users would be able to register a new key with FCM.
I must be misunderstanding something fundamental here, and am not even sure what to be searching for.

```
// TODO: Find out how to generate new registration token as needed
const vapidKey = {vapidKey:"BLgq_6FY0suqAy9llMyYX03o9K9n4FHba1gCnPz6KmG9oh6K8v3Ws4SIG9KTILfN0_8np9PfT5bPqgTDXfCA9dc"};

async function fcm_init(){
    try{
        // TODO: user interaction for notification permission
        await Notification.requestPermission()
        const currentToken = await getToken(messaging,vapidKey);
        // TODO: Send token to server to save in tbl_fcm
        console.log(currentToken);
    }
    catch(err){
        console.log(err);
    }
}fcm_init()
```

In this example, the vapidKey is hard-coded, but how would i go about getting a different key for each user in the app without manually doing so in the FCM Console UI?

[image: This is where i have generated the key to get a token for a user. This is what im trying to avoid doing manually for each user on the system.]

This is where i have generated the key to get a token for a user. This is what im trying to avoid doing manually for each user on the system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The vapidKey is needed for identifying the app (not the user). This is mentioned in the second screenshot "Firebase Cloud Messaging can use Application Identity key pairs to connect with external push services".

With this information, your app can generate an FCM Token (or registration token) in the client:

`const currentToken = await getToken(messaging,vapidKey);`

You can use these FCM tokens to send messages to a specific device. These FCM Tokens identify the device (user) and they will be different for each one.

Check this [example](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message#send-messages-to-specific-devices) on how you would send a message from the back end to a specific device using it's FCM token (registration token).

Comment: Thanks for the help Gerardo! I thought i might me conflating vapidkeys with FCM tokens, but whenever i attempt to generate a new token, I receive the same one, unless i manually delete the keypair from the console and generate a new one, then use that to generate a new token. I have yet to get deleteToken() to run, is that what i am missing to generate a new FCM token? In any case, how do i end up with a different token per user ? (Firebase v9.16 FWIW)

Comment: try accessing your app on a different browser or machine, the FCM token then should be different.